# Need help installing Pioneer car stereo in 2006 Hyundai Sonata (power antenna)

Tags: electrical, wiring, audio, sonata, installation

I have a 2006 Hyundai Sonata and am switching over my brand new radio from my old car. The radio I have is a Pioneer AVH-2800BS. According to Crutchfield (which I know and trust by heart!), it says "The wiring harness does not have a power antenna connection, so you'll need to connect your new stereo's power antenna wire directly to your vehicle's power antenna connection." I need help with what to do there. I don't understand how to do that.

Also, it says "When installing this adapter, you'll need to adjust four level controls to match the output of your new stereo to the input of the factory amp(s)." What does that even mean, and how do I do that???

Comment: I'm assuming from what you said, you bought this from Crutchfield. I installed a new Pioneer stereo I purchased from them into my '08 Azera. I had to call them twice for a couple of things. Their help desk is over the top in the help department. Give them a call and they will hook you up. There is no doubt in my mind about this. Crutchfield gives lifetime product support and their guys are on top of it without an issue. They know their stuff.

Comment: I surely will do that. I use Crutchfield because of the amazing service they give!!!!

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to be about a different adapter that is used to connect your stereo to an amplifier, not an antenna adapter.

Answer (score 2):

I have an '08 Azera (which I mentioned in the comments). The Azera has a powered antenna, but not the electric kind which goes up in down. It's an antenna which resides in the back glass. It has a power booster which must be powered in order for the radio to pick up radio stations. In the Pioneer wiring harness, it should be a blue w/ white stripe wire (one which isn't used for anything else ... it should be marked as antenna, I believe). This needs to get attached directly to your cars wiring harness, as it appears the connector does not come with it. The tough thing to figure out is which exact wire this will need to be connected to. More than likely, all the other wires should be accounted for in the car side plug, so shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Conversely, if your Sonata doesn't have the in window antenna, you won't need to worry about this wire. Tape it off so it doesn't short to anything and don't worry about it.

As far as adjusting the stereo as you stated in your last para, I believe this means you need to adjust the levels through the soft controls of the head unit itself. There should be settings you can play with to make things right with fader (front to rear/right to left). You should also be able to control the amount of boost the stereo puts out through these as well. If it sounds good after you get things hooked up, just don't worry about it (which is most likely what will happen, anyway).